# Mouse Buffer Menu with keyboard

Tags: emacs

is it possible to invoke the graphical menu that pops up with `'mouse-buffer-menu` (which in my case is assigned to `'[C-down-mouse-1]`) without actually hitting the mouse? When I invoke `M-x mouse-buffer-menu` emacs tells me

```
execute-extended-command: mouse-buffer-menu must be bound to an event with parameters
```

Is it possible, to generate such an event?

What I would like to have is a list (i.e. a graphical popup menu), where I can choose between the set of open buffers by selecting them using the UP/DOWN keys. I am well aware of `buffer-menu`, but unfortunately, that only provides a read-only list of all buffers, without the option of choosing one.

Kind regards,
mefiX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit of digging and playing I created an event and passed it to `mouse-buffer-menu`.

You can play with the numbers in the list for the desired effect.

```
(setq my-dummy-event `(mouse-1 (,(selected-window) 0 (0 . 0) 0 nil 0 (0 . 0) nil nil nil) 1))

(mouse-buffer-menu my-dummy-event)
```

Look at the emacs manual node for [Click Events](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Click-Events.html#Click-Events) to find out the structure of the event list.

As a side note have you considered alternatives for buffer selection such as [ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings%28global-set-key) or using something like `bs-show` to chose your buffer:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'bs-show)
```

using `a` to toggle all buffers.

You can also find better alternatives here:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryBufferSwitching

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I am additionally using tabbar.el to switch between buffers. But during work I figured out that I use C-mouse-1 for mouse-buffer-menu very often, but switching to the mouse was going on my nerves :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late: what about `list-buffers` (`C-x C-b`) ? It give a buffer list from which you can select the buffer to show...